# Calculate cumulative duration of a pandas datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'time': ['2014-05-01 18:47:05', '2014-05-01 18:47:06', '2014-05-02 18:47:08', '2014-05-02 18:47:10', '2014-05-02 18:47:11']})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

This gives the following dataframe

```
              time
0 2014-05-01 18:47:05
1 2014-05-01 18:47:06
2 2014-05-02 18:47:08
3 2014-05-02 18:47:10
4 2014-05-02 18:47:11
```

I would like to add another column that calculates the duration of the time column in seconds as follow

```
    time                   duration
0 2014-05-01 18:47:05          0
1 2014-05-01 18:47:06          1 
2 2014-05-02 18:47:08          3 
3 2014-05-02 18:47:10          5
4 2014-05-02 18:47:11          6
```

Obviously, I can do some looping and make a difference manually but I suspect this is not a pythonic way to this. Is there any function in pandas that would simplify this process?

Comment: Just a question: have you noticed rows 1 and 2 actually have more than a day difference? Do you just want the span in times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you the total difference in seconds (i.e., counting differences in dates too):

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(
                     df['time'] - df['time'][0]
                   ).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['duration'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                    .diff()
                    .fillna(0)
                    .dt.total_seconds()
                    .astype(int)
                    .cumsum()
                 )
```

Alternative solution:

```
a = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df['duration'] = a.sub(a.iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
                 time  duration
0 2014-05-01 18:47:05         0
1 2014-05-01 18:47:06         1
2 2014-05-02 18:47:08         3
3 2014-05-02 18:47:10         5
4 2014-05-02 18:47:11         6
```

Explanation:

1. First convert values [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with same dates
2. Get difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) or subtract first value by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html)
3. Last convert to `seconds` by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)

Comment: ```
a = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df['duration'] = a.sub(a.iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

perfect and concise.

the accepted answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can negate the first time entry from your series and convert to seconds:

```
df['duration'] = (df['time'] - df['time'].iloc[0]).dt.seconds

print(df)

#                  time  duration
# 0 2014-05-01 18:47:05         0
# 1 2014-05-01 18:47:06         1
# 2 2014-05-02 18:47:08         3
# 3 2014-05-02 18:47:10         5
# 4 2014-05-02 18:47:11         6
```