# How can I calculate the duration of a column, grouping by another column (Python or R)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe, `df`, with the following data:

```
           ID            DateTime        

           A             12/13/2019 6:35:48PM
           A             12/13/2019 6:35:49PM
           A             12/13/2019 6:35:50PM
           B             12/13/2019 7:00:00PM
           B             12/13/2019 7:00:05PM
           C             12/13/2019 8:00:05PM
```

Desired outcome:

```
          ID              Duration

          A                  3 sec
          B                  5 sec
          C                  1 sec
```

Code I am performing using Python:

```py
df.sum(group_by['ID'])
```

How can I calculate the duration of a column, grouping by another column?

Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate cumulative duration of a pandas datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853295/calculate-cumulative-duration-of-a-pandas-datetime-column)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't include the 'group_by' condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in R with `dplyr` and `magrittr` packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
x <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","C"),
                 DateTime =  c("12/13/2019 6:35:48PM", "12/13/2019 6:35:49PM",
                               "12/13/2019 6:35:50PM","12/13/2019 7:00:00PM", 
                               "12/13/2019 7:00:05PM","12/13/2019 8:00:05PM"))
x$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(x$DateTime, format = c("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
x %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(dif = max(DateTime)- min(DateTime)) %>% 
   select(ID, dif) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
 ID    dif   
 <fct> <drtn>
1 A     2 secs
2 B     5 secs
3 C     0 secs
```

Comment: Yes, I will work in R on this particular problem, as I see the outcome will work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are the timestamps already sorted? You probably want to find the earliest and latest timestamp and subtract them for each ID.

Comment: Hi, thank you, yes, they are already sorted. I am essentially wanting to take the sum of each ID.   (Find the duration spent for each ID, creating a new 'duration' column that reflects this)

Comment: I think what you want is not exactly the sum, I see that it is the difference of the last timestamp and the earliest for a given ID

Comment: I see, the reason I am saying 'sum' is because sometimes, there may be 'breaks' within the group, giving a false duration time

Comment: So you can have the following series of messages: A, A, B, A, A? What would be the duration that you want in this case? Is it between the first A and last A, or you want to extract 2 durations, the ones before B and the ones after B?

Comment: I would like to first group_by the ID, so that these are all together. Then I would like to take the sum of each of these groups, adding a new duration column

Comment: Ok but you mentioned something about the breaks, if a series of event A has other events like B and C in between, do you wish to extract the duration of the first group of A and the duration of the second group of A separately, or do you want to ignore the fact that there were events between apparitions of A?

Comment: ok thank you for your input. I will re-word. I am still learning Pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom function and aggregate of over each series grouped by `'ID'`

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime

def duration(series):
    return (max(series) - min(series)).total_seconds()

df.groupby['ID'].agg({'DateTime' : duration})
```

Comment: Hello, I seem to be getting a: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable error when I run this

Comment: There's a chance that you're missing brackets somewhere. Maybe you're trying to index something that's not a list. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261055/method-object-is-not-subscriptable-dont-know-whats-wrong/35261082) might help.