# total sum of time in hours due to a change in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to obtain the sum in hours of datetime when the value of my `count` column increases from zero to 1 and also drops from 1 to zero.
Example data is as below:

```
Datetime       |   count  
2020-02-01-00  |    0
2020-02-01-01  |    0
2020-02-01-02  |    0
2020-02-01-03  |    1
2020-02-01-04  |    0
2020-02-01-05  |    1
```

So it should create a new column called "sum of hours" and sums the total of hours the count value changes from 0 to 1 and also from 1 to zero. Example solution is as below:

```
Datetime       |   count  | sum of hours
2020-02-01-00  |    0     |   0hours
2020-02-01-01  |    0     |   0hours
2020-02-01-02  |    0     |   0hours
2020-02-01-03  |    1     |   3Hours
2020-02-01-04  |    0     |   1hour
2020-02-01-05  |    1     |   1hour
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853295/calculate-cumulative-duration-of-a-pandas-datetime-column) might help to calculate the difference in seconds. **You can adapt that to calculate the difference in hours**.:

```
   df['sum of hours'] = pd.to_timedelta(
       df['Datetime'] - df['Datetime'][0]
        ).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```